# How to get dimmer on specific card to toggle rather than all my card gallery using Semantic UI and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, semantic-ui, dom-manipulation

I have a gallery of avatars I want to show my user, which are shown in the card format of Semantic-UI. I want the user to click on one of the images which then triggers Semantic's dimmer to appear in that specific image's place.

What I currently get is that all the images get the dimmer to appear on them instead of the specific one I want. Here is the code that puts the dimmer on all images:

```js
$(".selectavatar img").hover(function() {
  $('.selectavatar img').removeClass('selectedImage');
  $(this).toggleClass("selectedImage");
});

$(".selectavatar img").click(function() {
  $(".ui.dimmer").dimmer("toggle");
});
```

```html
    <!--gallery goes here-->
    <div class="ui three column grid selectavatar">
        <div class="five wide column">
            <div class="ui segment">
                <form action="/account/<%=currentUser._id%>?_method=PUT" method="POST">
                    <input name="user[image]" type"submit" value = "image1.jpg" class="hidden" />
                    <img name="user[image]" src = "image1.jpg" width=300>
                    <div class="ui dimmer">
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="center">
                               <button class="ui button blue" type="Submit">
                                    <i class="user icon"></i> Select Avatar
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>                
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="five wide column">
            <div class="ui segment">
                <form action="/account/<%=currentUser._id%>?_method=PUT" method="POST">
                    <input name="user[image]" type"submit" value = "image2.png" class="hidden" />
                    <img name="user[image]" src = "image2.png" width=300>
                    <div class="ui dimmer">
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="center">
                                   <button class="ui button blue" type="Submit">
                                        <i class="user icon"></i> Select Avatar
                                    </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>                
            </div>
        </div>
```

The way I envisioned it was that I'll add the class `.selectedImage` on the image the user wants, then I would be able to toggle the dimmer if `selectedImage` exists. But when I do use that as so:

```
$(".selectavatar img.selectedImage").click(function() {
  $(".ui.dimmer").dimmer("toggle");
});
```

then nothing appears, no dimmer whatsoever!

What am I doing wrong?

As a side note, I need to figure out how to generate a gallery from a folder of images using EJS and NodeJS, instead of having to hard code each image. I guess the right thing to do would be a seperate question for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will dim all .ui.dimmer divs when you click an image:

```
$(".selectavatar img").click(function() {
  $(".ui.dimmer").dimmer("toggle");
});
```

This code will dim only the .ui.dimmer div which is located in the same parent container as the clicked image:

```
$(".selectavatar img").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find(".ui.dimmer").dimmer("toggle");
});
```

Part 2

Your code will set a click handler on all img.selectedImage which exist when you set the event handlers.  Unfortunately no images have the selectedImage class at that point so it doesn't work.

```
$(".selectavatar img.selectedImage").click(function() {
  //code
});
```

This code will do the same, but it only requires .selectavatar to exist when the event handler is set up:

```
$(".selectavatar").on("click", "img.selectedImage", function() {
  //code
});
```

Comment: awesome! thanks for that James. Follow up question for the second part though, I understood your explanation, but how is it different having 'img.selectedImage' as an argument to the on click event handler?

Comment: In your code you assigned a "direct" event handler, my version is a [delegated](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) handler.